# Parsing Data from a website in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

This [website](http://www.omatlahdot.fi/omatlahdot/web?command=fullscreen&stop=1020455) that keeps updating some live information about the bus timings in Helsinki.

I want to parse the live information from the website and display it on my WP7 phone. The user needs to enter the bus stop number and the WP7 app should show the buses/trams currently in the bus stop.

Is there any way I could obtain the real time information from the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source of the website (http://www.omatlahdot.fi/omatlahdot/web?command=fullscreen&stop=1020455) -- in IE right-click on the page and select View Source -- you'll see that there's really very little in the actual source file, in particular none of the data is there. All of the hard work is coming from the referenced javascript file scripts/fullscreen_header.js (full path is http://www.omatlahdot.fi/omatlahdot/scripts/fullscreen_header.js). You want to download that .js file and study how it retrieves data with AJAX calls. Start with the reloadPage function.

You can make these same calls (e.g., using WebClient) to retrieve the data into your application. If you want to extract the data from the returned HTML, I'd consider parsing it simply as a string since I am assuming that it would have a very regular structure and dragging in a general-purpose HTML parser would probably be overkill.

Alternatively, you might find out if the omatlahodot.fi provides the data as JSON or XML feeds, so you don't have to "screen-scrape" the HTML. I don't read Finnish, so I can't help you with that. Look around on their websites (maybe a section called "dev" or "api") or send them an email inquiry.

Please let us know how it works out!